# Saída em json com json_encode()

Tags: php, ajax, json, array, pdo

> json_encode() — Retorna a representação JSON de um valor

Se eu fizer:

```
$foo = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
echo json_encode($foo);
```

Vou conseguir:

```
["a","b","c","d","e"]
```

Até ai tudo bem, estou pegando um array e transformando em um objeto json.

Agora se eu tento fazer uma consulta e retornar um array multidimensional para transformar em json não funciona.

**Exemplo:**

```
include '../db/pdo.php';
$sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT  * FROM CLIENTES WHERE ID > 0');
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($result);
```

O que estou esquecendo ? Ambos estão pegando um array e transformando em JSON.

**Saída do array:**

```html
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=22)
      'CODIGO' => string '1' (length=1)
      'NOME' => string 'MARIA DA SILVA' (length=14)
      'TIPOPESSOA' => string 'F' (length=1)
      'CPF' => string '12345678912' (length=11)
      'CGC' => null
      'CONTACORRENTE' => null
      'REGIAO' => null
      'ENDERECO' => null
      'NUMERO' => null
      'SETOR' => null
      'CIDADE' => null
      'UF' => null
      'CEP' => null
      'FONE' => null
      'FAXCEL' => null
      'ENDENDERECO_1' => null
      'NUMERO_1' => null
      'SETOR_1' => null
      'CIDADE_1' => null
      'UF_1' => null
      'CEP_1' => null
      'FONE_1' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=22)
      'CODIGO' => string '2' (length=1)
      'NOME' => string 'SU�LLEM DA SILVA' (length=24)
      'TIPOPESSOA' => string 'F' (length=1)
      'CPF' => string '12345678912' (length=11)
      'CGC' => null
      'CONTACORRENTE' => null
      'REGIAO' => null
      'ENDERECO' => string 'ENDERECO' (length=19)
      'NUMERO' => string '401' (length=3)
      'SETOR' => string 'SETOR' (length=8)
      'CIDADE' => string 'BUENO' (length=13)
      'UF' => string 'RO' (length=2)
      'CEP' => string '12345678912' (length=8)
      'FONE' => string '12345678912' (length=10)
      'FAXCEL' => null
      'ENDENDERECO_1' => null
      'NUMERO_1' => null
      'SETOR_1' => null
      'CIDADE_1' => null
      'UF_1' => null
      'CEP_1' => null
      'FONE_1' => null
```

Usando `json_last_error()` me retorna `5 = JSON_ERROR_UTF8`.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31449/discussion-on-question-by-gabriel-rodrigues-saida-em-json-com-json-encode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver o problema de códificação percorri o array criando um novo e utilizando `utf8_encode()`  para deixar tudo com `utf-8`.

```
$novo = array();
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
   foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
     $novo[$key][$k] = utf8_encode($v);
   }
}

echo json_encode($novo);
```

Comment: Não é uma solução adequada. Resolve aparentemente mas é uma gambiarra. Vc deve procurar resolver o problema na raíz. Eu acho que os dados estão sendo gravados com um encode diferente do que está configurado o banco de dados.

Comment: @DanielOmine concordo contigo, essa solução é a mesma de uma library chamada adodb, me parece uma gambiarra e gasta um tempo refazendo o array, criei esse tópico para  tentar centralizar o problema do charset do banco http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97469/17658

Comment: péssimo exemplo sobre adodb.. rsrs.. mas entendi o intuito.. Eu vi o link com a pergunta sobre setar o charset no firebird.. mas acho que vc ainda não entendeu que o buraco está mais embaixo. Eu suspeito que o problema está na forma como salva os dados, conforme descrevi no comentário acima. Procure no script que faz o insert. Mas também pode diagnosticar no momento do select usando `mb_detect_encoding()`. Saliento que é uma suspeita, mas é o primeiro teste que eu faria para encontrar o problema.

Comment: @DanielOmine pra você ter ideia esse banco é utilizado em uma aplicação Delphi e  em uma web,  eu acabei de passar por uma mudança de adodb para pdo por causa do melhor desempenho apresentado no pdo e agora estou tendo esses probleminhas com charset

Comment: @DanielOmine se no Delphi eles conseguem salvar os dados e pega-los codificado eu deveria fazer também, você acha que o problema está no banco ou na  configuração do pdo ?

Comment: puts... é disso que comentei umas 3 vezes acima.. sobre falar dos detalhes relevantes.. Isso sobre o banco ser usado por outra aplicação numa linguagem totalmente diferente, muda bastante o rumo das coisas.. mas dá mais certeza de que o problema pode estar no momento que os dados são salvos. Pode estar sendo salvo num encode diferente de UTF8.. entendeu ? vc precisa procurar saber como que o aplicativo em delphi está salvando, qual o charset desse aplicativo. Não deve ser difícil.. provavelmente está usando  windows-1252, ISO8859-1 ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score 2):

Como alternativa você pode usar `SET names` do mysql:

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);
$dbh->exec('SET names utf8');
```

Sendo Firebird (não pude testar):

```
$str_conn = 'firebird:host=localhost;dbname=/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/employee.fdb;charset=UTF8';
$dbh = new PDO($str_conn, 'sysdba', 'senha');
```

Acaso não resolva, uma alternativa a sua resposta, seria usar o `array_map`

```
$result = array_map('utf8_encode', $result);
```

Ou `array_walk_recursive` pra casos aonde tiver arrays multidimensionais:

```
function encode_items(&$item, $key)
{
    $item = utf8_encode($item);
}

array_walk_recursive($jobs, 'encode_items');
```

<sub>Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3913024/1518921</sub>

Comment: Sem duvidas a sua resposta seria ideal se eu estivesse utilizando o mysql, porém uso firebird, estou tentando resolver este grande enigma aqui:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97469/17658 pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Entendi @GabrielRodrigues por isto sempre recomendo você seguir o http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, pois isto sempre ajuda a formular respostas mais definitivas, veja eu atualizei a resposta, não pude testar.

Comment: Fiz um benchmack comparando o `array_walk_recursive + função` vs `2 foreach`, os foreach são 46% mais rápidos. vou ler este artigo, obrigado.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Excelente!! Depois me diga o `array_map`, note que o `array_walk_recursive` é mais usado pra multidimensional e por isso deve se mais lento.

Comment: O Desempenho do array_map é bem semelhante ao do array_walk_recursive, ambas funções resolveram o problema usando um array multidimensional, tem alguma peculiaridade do walk_recursive para ele ser mais utilizado ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues sim ele é usado com arrays multi-dimensionais, o que  não é o seu caso atual :) - Uma pergunta `;charset=UTF8';` não funcionou?

Comment: Não, este foi o meu primeiro teste :(